# bitwise OR (on array)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I need to perform bitwise OR of two arrays of byte in Java. How can I do so?

```
byte a= new byte[256];
byte b= new byte[256];

byte c; /*it should contain information i.e bitwise OR of a and b */
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to use a `BitSet`.
That class already has a `void or(BitSet bs)` method to use.

```
byte[] a = new byte[256];
byte[] b = new byte[256];
byte[] c = new byte[256];

//fill BitSets with values from your byte-Arrays
BitSet bsa = BitSet.valueOf(a);
BitSet bsb = BitSet.valueOf(b);

//perform OR
bsa.or(bsb);

//write bsa to byte-Array c
c = bsa.toByteArray();
```

Comment: It would be nice if somebody could test this. Unfortunately I can't test it right now but I'm pretty sure it works. You're also welcome to edit!

Answer (score 2):

Thats as simple as using the | operator and a loop:

```
public static byte[] byteOr(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    int len = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        result[i] = (byte) (a[i] | b[i])
    return result;
}
```